# i want to change the column name of a table through sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use `queryInterface` to change the name of a column in a table, but the code below does not work. Why is this?

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const queryInterface = sequelize.getQueryInterface();
```

> error : queryInterface is not a function

Comment: take a look in [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/query-interface.html)

Answer (score 1):

`queryInterface` is available on your Sequelize instance. see [Obtaining the query interface](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/query-interface.html)

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize(/* ... */);
const queryInterface = sequelize.getQueryInterface();
```

Comment: throw new Error('Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0') it gives this error ,how to resolve this

Comment: @sumantapatra What version of `sequelize` do you use?

Comment: `6.3.5 version`

Comment: @sumantapatra You should supply the dialect when you initialize sequelize

Comment: @sumantapatra Please follow https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html